# How can we remove this title bar overlapping in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: gnome, extension

[image]

The Gnome Desktop text is overlapping with the other extension icons as one can see in the picture. I tried to find a solution to this but I am not able to get one. I think someone might know how to solve this.

Thank you!!

Comment: yet another extension you have added which can be removed perhaps?

Comment: How can we know what extension has caused this? (Most extensions I added seemed  useful by reading the context)

Comment: You do not appear to use Unity desktop, but the default Gnome Shell desktop. Please remove tag "Unity" and add appropriate tag instead. Clearly, using a more compact font and removing some of the extensions could solve the issue.

Comment: I try putting the exact tags, in fact all apt tags for a question, but it requires more reputation credits required to do it. So I have to choose whatever is available. :) By the way out of curiosity, is Unity desktop better than Gnome? Edit: Added the gnome tag.

Comment: If it is the number of extension that has caused this, then extension list extension should adjust it. I do not think it is the no. of extension has caused this because there is space on the title bar on the right hand side. Also there must be something to reduce the test of namely Applications List, Places, etc to a few characters if something like more no. of extensions happen. What do you say?

Comment: Changing fonts and/or removing items is a workaround.  I believe Microsoft also pondered this issue as their solution was to create a sort of a drop-down window that reveals hidden tray items.  Obviously this solution would have to come from a code change in the Window Manager itself.